# jQuery ".button" decoration disappears when ASP.NET button is clicked?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, updatepanel

From the jquery UI you can now apply `.button()` to an anchor, a button, a submit button etc.
I've got a simple asp.net button that looks like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnFindSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" 
                        onclick="btnFindSearch_Click" />
```

It is however inside of an updatepanel like so:

```
 <div id="dialog" title="Select Address">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upNewUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="search" style="width:100%; text-align:center;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFindSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
                <asp:Button ID="btnFindSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" 
                    onclick="btnFindSearch_Click" />
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
```

In my jquery I can do:

`$('#btnFindSearch').button();`

And it gives me the jquery ui look of a button...awesome I thought.  But the minute I click my button the button returns to the plain old looking asp.net server button.  Its as if the `.button()` is no longer applied.

Is this due to the fact that it is inside an UpdatePanel or what could be causing this???

Comment: Here is the jquery ui documentation on .button as well http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with the [jQuery **livequery** plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery).

It can be used to define a function for all the elements what are currently in the dom and those which wud be added later.. that would solve most of your problems.

Here is an example usage:

```
$("#btnFindSearch").livequery(function(){$(this).button();})
```

Comment: Use jquery live where?  This answer doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I know what live is, but it cannot be applied to this situation - did you even read my post?

Comment: this is the exact link http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery/livequery#matchedFn isnt this what u want?

Comment: How do you use live to apply .button() ?

Comment: If this is all it takes +1 million upvotes, but I dont think its that simple.  Either way I will give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: +1 I did not know such an extension existed .. I wonder how it works (e.g. is there polling magic or a browser event or ...?)

Comment: @pst - dont get too happy I could of sworn I tried this last week with nada results, but then again I don't remember if my syntax was spot on, Ill have to try it tomorrow.  If it works I might re-accept to Parv Sharma, this is just so much simplier.

Comment: @ParvSharma live (works on event bubbling) != livequery -- I updated the post.

Comment: @pst right this is a plugin...err and the plugin site is down!

Comment: Here's the link to the plugin: https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery/downloads (my FYI) for tomorrow morning.

Comment: This sure did work - thanks a treat much simpler, and although its a seperate plugin I could certainly use this in the near future for some other things that have been bugging me.

Comment: hey no need of thankx i gt my answer marked :) thats all i needed

Answer (score 6):

This is because on the button click a *server PostBack occurs* and the original DOM elements are replaced.

UpdatePanel is not particularly clever. It just replaces *all of the child content* with the new HTML sent from the server (think `innerHTML = severStuff`). The newly created DOM elements are thus "not decorated". The `.button()` magic needs to be run again on the new DOM elements.

---

Barring a better way to handle this, of which I do not know, here is a [helpful class for inline script blocks](http://zsoltmiskolczi.blogspot.com/2011/01/aspnet-web-server-control-for-rendering.html) that automatically handles different scenarios. It's sort of a kludge and "hackish", but it does work rather well (we use a modified version).

Usage might look like (this must be **inside** the [updated] UpdatePanel for it work on partial PostBacks):

```
<UpdatePanel ...>
  <OtherControls ...>
  // Put other controls first, because this will be rendered in-order
  // (which should usually be last!) in a normal/full PostBack.
  // It will use the appropriate "RegisterScript" for partial PostBacks.
  <InlineScript runat="server">
    <script>
        // Add .button() stuff here - note that InlineScript is last
        // so the previous (control) DOM nodes exist already in current
        // browser implementations, even if there is no "DOM loaded" per-se...
        // -- or --
        jQuery(function ($) {
            // Add .button() stuff here; using $.ready here might (??)
            // actually cause the browser to update the UI first...
            // ...but it will guarantee the DOM is completely loaded.
        })
    </script>
  </InlineScript>
</UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Err but I have to have it inside an updatepanel due to other parts of the application.  Especially since I am using jquery ui dialog...if you have a jquery ui dialog object and you allow for a postback the dialog closes...so you have to do this stuff in an updatepanel.  Is there anything I can do to "decorate" the button again???  Should I look into `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScript` and just reapplying the .button in the code behind?

Comment: @oJM86o That is one way. Another way is to look into the Page Request Manager. I am not sure what would happen with the UI experience if setting from JavaScript after every PostBack ...

Comment: you mentioned the .button() needs to be run again on the new DOM elements...The issue is the click of that button is causing the postback..where on earth can I recall .button() if I am on the server side now (code behind page).

Comment: @oJM86o `.button()` is client-side only. The information is never sent to the server. The button click fires a PostBack because `AutoPostBack=true` (the default).

Comment: I guess when I get back into the office tomorrow I will look at applying the RegisterCLientScript via the ScriptManager object...err I hate how the communication between client side vs server side makes web development all the more difficult!!!

Comment: I know that already...I was asking how could I apply .button if I am on the server side code now..I guess Ill go back to my initial RegisterClientScript tomorrow morning and see if that works.

Comment: +1 anyway..this tells me I'm not crazy and im on the right page.

Comment: @oJM86o I would say that the `.button()` decoration should always be applied -- e.g. never send the information to the server -- on *all* applicable PostBacks.

Comment: pst I dont think you understand what I'm saying. I do apply .button() to the button in the document ready function.  My issue is once I click the server side button I've lost this due to it being inside an updatepanel.  But how on earth (besides using the scriptmanager object and applying registerclientscript would I ever call .button() being that jquery is client side...)  I wonder didn't anyone think of this stuff when this stuff was designed.  I mean who on earth is going to use jquery without having server side code available...sure if you are a florist designing static pages.

Comment: @oJM86o I have added a useful link in the post. The PostBack of an UpdatePanel does *not* trigger a document-ready as it is done via XHR. Remember that `$.ready` will fire immediately if the DOM is already ready so it can be used in the InlineScript above as a quick work-about.

Comment: I read it but don't understand how I could apply it to my issue :(.

Comment: @oJM86o I hope the example will clear things up a little bit :)

Comment: so place this under the rest of my jquery, and after a full postback it will call this script auto- magically?

Comment: @oJM86o Under the other controls but **inside** the UpdatePanel. The `InlineScript` linked differs from the standard ASP.NET Script controls in that it will *run on partial postbacks as well* . So, anything that needs to be run "everytime" can be put in it.

Comment: within the update panel correct?  Could you edit your post to show that specifically?

Comment: I'd upvote 100 more if I could.  I'll give it a try tomorrow at the office...this had me not sleeping for a few days...programming is a full time job - i just wish managers knew what we go through.

Comment: thanks for the help but I had to accept the other answer, its a clean solution and that plug in does what I need it to do.  I thought originally he was only referring to `.live()`.